# Selection Symbol dissapears when map is zoomed

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have a base map layer with a feature layer of maps added.  A table of the routes is generated by `FeatureTable` and the color of the route changes from green to red whenever a route is clicked on the table or on the map.  My problem is the route changes back to green with a red outline if I zoom in or out with the map.  If I click on the route it will turn back to red, but I need it to stay red.  I have shown my code below.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
     var map, stateBaseMap, geometryLayer, routeFeature, routeDataFeature, myFeatureTable,
        stateBaseMapUrl, geometryLayerUrl, routeFeatureUrl, routeDataFeatureUrl, routeChange;

  require([ "esri/map",
            "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
            "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer",
            "esri/tasks/GeometryService",
            "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
            "esri/dijit/FeatureTable",
             "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
             "esri/Color", 
             "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
              "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
              "esri/geometry/Extent",
              "esri/graphicsUtils",
              "esri/tasks/query",
              "dojo/dom",
              "dojo/parser",
              "dojo/ready",
              "dojo/on"],
    function(Map,
             ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, 
             ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer, 
             GeometryService, 
             FeatureLayer,
             FeatureTable,
             SimpleLineSymbol,
             Color,
             ContentPane, 
             BorderContainer,
             Extent, 
             graphicsUtils, 
             Query,
              dom, 
              parser, 
              ready, 
              on) {
      parser.parse();

      ready(function(){
            esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/llr/llrproxy";
            esri.config.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = false;
            esri.config.defaults.io.corsDetection = false;
            stateBaseMapUrl = document.getElementById("shipment_stateBaseMapServiceURL").value;
            geometryLayerUrl = document.getElementById("shipment_geometryServiceURL").value;
            routeFeatureUrl = document.getElementById("shipment_routeLayerURL").value;
            map = new Map("map");
            stateBaseMap = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(stateBaseMapUrl);
            map.addLayer(stateBaseMap);
            geometryLayer = new GeometryService(geometryLayerUrl);
            map.addLayer(geometryLayer);

            routeFeature = new FeatureLayer(routeFeatureUrl, {
                mode : FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
                outFields : [ "*" ],
                visible:true,
                id : "routeFeature"
            });
            var selectionSymbol = new  SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([255,0,0]),6);

            routeFeature.setSelectionSymbol(selectionSymbol);

            map.addLayer(routeFeature);
            on(routeFeature, "load", function(){
                loadTable();
              });

            function loadTable(){
                    myFeatureTable = new FeatureTable({
                    featureLayer : routeFeature,
                    map : map, 
                    editable: false,
                    showGridMenu:false,
                    gridOptions: {
                          selectionMode: "single"
                      },
                    editable: true,
                    fieldInfos: [
                              {
                                name: 'ROUTE_ID', 
                                visible: false
                              },
                              {
                                name: 'ORIGIN', 
                                alias: 'Entry State'
                              },
                              {
                                name: 'ROUTE_DESC', 
                                alias: 'Route Description'
                              },
                              {
                                name: 'DESTNATION', 
                                alias: 'Exit State'
                              }
                    ],
                    menuFunctions: [
                                        { label: "Enter a new route.",  callback: enterNewRoute }
                                  ]

                  }, 'myTableNode');

                  myFeatureTable.startup();
            }
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be some other code, which is clearing the selection. Otherwise it should work. [Here](http://jsbin.com/kipududaxa/edit?html,output) is a JSBin showing the selection remains even after zooming/panning. I have taken the sample from esri website and modified similar to your logic except, the loadTable part.

Comment: Your example showed me the problem but I don't know how to fix it.  The Selection Symbol is loaded first and the rest of the map layers are loaded on top of them.  That is what is happening on my map.  The red Selection Symbol is loaded first after the zoom and then the green routes are loaded on top of them.  The same thing happens with your example.  Zoom out and the red diamond is displayed first after the zoom and the green data is displayed next.  If you zoom out far enough the red diamond gets covered up.  Is there a way to reverse the display order?

Answer (score 0):

I found changing `mode : FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,`   to `mode : FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,` solved the problem but the problem was still there if I zoomed or moved the map.  Also, I can only use the `MODE_SNAPSHOT` because my map has a small number of features.  To solve the zoom/move problem I redrew the route after the zoom or move was finished.

```
var map, stateBaseMap, geometryLayer, routeFeature, routeDataFeature, myFeatureTable,
    stateBaseMapUrl, geometryLayerUrl, routeFeatureUrl, routeDataFeatureUrl, routeChange,
    mapUpdateEnd, mapZoomEnd, mapDragEnd;

require([   "esri/map",
  "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
  "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer",
  "esri/tasks/GeometryService",
  "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
  "esri/dijit/FeatureTable",
  "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
  "esri/Color", 
  "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
  "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
  "esri/geometry/Extent",
  "esri/graphicsUtils",
  "esri/tasks/query",
  "esri/tasks/QueryTask",
  "dojo/dom",
  "dojo/parser",
  "dojo/ready",
  "dojo/on"],
function(Map,
     ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, 
     ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer, 
     GeometryService, 
     FeatureLayer,
     FeatureTable,
     SimpleLineSymbol,
     Color,
     ContentPane, 
     BorderContainer,
     Extent, 
     graphicsUtils, 
     Query,
     QueryTask,
      dom, 
      parser, 
      ready, 
      on) {
parser.parse();

ready(function(){
    esri.config.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/llr/llrproxy";
    esri.config.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = false;
    esri.config.defaults.io.corsDetection = false;
    stateBaseMapUrl = document.getElementById("shipment_stateBaseMapServiceURL").value;
    geometryLayerUrl = document.getElementById("shipment_geometryServiceURL").value;
    routeFeatureUrl = document.getElementById("shipment_routeLayerURL").value;
    map = new Map("map");
    stateBaseMap = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(stateBaseMapUrl);
    map.addLayer(stateBaseMap);
    geometryLayer = new GeometryService(geometryLayerUrl);
    map.addLayer(geometryLayer);

    routeFeature = new FeatureLayer(routeFeatureUrl, {
        mode : FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
        outFields : [ "*" ],
        visible:true,
        id : "routeFeature"
    });
    var selectionSymbol = new  SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([255,0,0]),6);

    routeFeature.setSelectionSymbol(selectionSymbol);

    map.addLayer(routeFeature);

    on(routeFeature, "load", function(){
        mapZoomEnd = map.on("zoom-end",function(){
            mapZoomEnd.remove();
        });


        loadTable();

            mapZoomEnd = map.on("zoom-end",function(){
                reDrawRoute(document.getElementById("shipment_currentRouteId").value);
            });

            mapDragEnd = map.on("mouse-drag-end",function(){
                reDrawRoute(document.getElementById("shipment_currentRouteId").value);
            });

            myFeatureTable.on("row-select", function(evt){
                zoomToRoute(evt[0].data.ROUTE_ID);
              });

      });


    function zoomToRoute(routeId){
        if(routeId != 0){
            var query = getQueryForRouteId(routeId);
            routeFeature.selectFeatures(query, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function(features){
                var extent = graphicsUtils.graphicsExtent(features).expand(1.25); 
                map.setExtent(extent);
            });
        }
    }

    function reDrawRoute(routeId){
        if(routeId != 0){
            var query = getQueryForRouteId(routeId);
            routeFeature.selectFeatures(query, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW);
        }
    }

    function getQueryForRouteId(routeId){
        var query = new Query();
        query.returnGeometry = true;
        query.outFields = [ "*" ];
        query.where = "ROUTE_ID = '" + routeId + "'" ;
        return query;
    }


    function loadTable(){
            myFeatureTable = new FeatureTable({
            featureLayer : routeFeature,
            map : map, 
            editable: false,
            showGridMenu:false,
            gridOptions: {
                  selectionMode: "single"
              },
            editable: true,
            fieldInfos: [
                      {
                        name: 'ROUTE_ID', 
                        visible: false
                      },
                      {
                        name: 'ORIGIN', 
                        alias: 'Entry State'
                      },
                      {
                        name: 'ROUTE_DESC', 
                        alias: 'Route Description'
                      },
                      {
                        name: 'DESTNATION', 
                        alias: 'Exit State'
                      }
            ]

          }, 'myTableNode');

            myFeatureTable.on('load', function () {
                myFeatureTable.grid.set('sort', [{ attribute: "ORIGIN" }]);
            });
          myFeatureTable.startup();

    }
  });
});
```